# Captions are great - if only I could keep just the x- caption and dump the Intensity caption in line plots

Tags: dm-script

The command

```
ImageDisplaySetCaptionOn( ImageDisplay imgDisp, Boolean on )
```

is great, but it turns all the captions on/off for line plots.
Is there any way to keep the abscissa caption and dump the ordinate (Intensity) caption?
Thanks!

Comment: If this is something you care about, you might consider submitting a feature request to Gatan's issue tracker. Accessible via [Gatan's Homepage.](https://www.gatan.com/resources/software) "ISSUE and BUG Reporting" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in current GMS versions up to 3.6.0.